# Sharepoint App model permission

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Could anyone please let me know whether giving Tenant permission to Full control automatically give me site collection full control?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right.

According to [Plan app permissions management in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219576%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) :

> If an app is granted permission to one scope, the permission also
>   applies to the children of that scope.

In your case since an app is granted permission to a tenancy, the app is also granted permission to each site collection (`SPSite` scope) that is contained within the `Tenancy` scope.